# Who was this US civil rights leader?

Tags: united-states, diplomacy, racism

Back in my high school days (I'm 23 now) we learned about a lot of topics but the one that stood out to me was the period of heavy segregation, racism and important historical figures from that time period that made black people or POC (people of color) have the same rights as their counterpart white people. We also delved into black history month and learned a lot about different figures there, but there was one person who we learned about who I wish I remembered and payed more attention to as I don't remember this persons name.

What I do remember is that the person in question was a leader figure and that he and a bunch of his colored friends would always get beaten up in public (especially in cafés), but being the person he was, he stuck to his beliefs and values. He believed in peaceful protest, non violent confrontations and so on. So what my history teacher told us is that he taught his people essentially how to take a beating without giving one back, and not resolve violence with violence but rather resolve it through diplomacy. I hope I’ve given enough information so that someone can please tell me this persons name, as I’ve completely forgotten it and wish I didn't.

Comment: Could this be [Martin Luther King Jr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Luther_King_Jr.)?  Could the cafe reference be to the [Atlanta Students movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlanta_Student_Movement)

Comment: "*Took a beating; kept on ticking*" just sounds a bit too much like the 1960's era Timex watch commercial. I will await developments.

Comment: There is no such single person. Bits of it sound like the lunch counter protests, but those happened half a decade after the Atlanta Bus Boycott, and half a century after the Pullman Porter's strike. CORE started the sit-in movement 2 decades earlier. Most likely you are either misremembering what was taught, or the teacher was confused, or a combination. Unless you can greatly clarify what you're asking, I'm not sure we can at this remove with the information provided figure out which it is.

Comment: It could be, its a long time ago since I graduated but ive never heard this story ever again after my teacher told us. I’m afraid I cant clarify any further as its years ago by now but I kept thinking who is this man. Its most likely either MLK or Macolm but I couldnt find any historical evidence that resembled what ive asked here.

Comment: My SWAG would be that its talking about John Lewis, as he went on to be rather famous, and those lunch-counter protests were a big part of his origin story. But he wasn't a leader of that action, and really there are any of a thousand people such a story could be about. Some are famous, some today are just quietly living their lives, like a latter-day [Cincinnatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucius_Quinctius_Cincinnatus)